# Ruby on Rails how to split two symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, split

I have this url

```
https://habrahabr.ru/post/340400/?utm_source=habrahabr&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=best
```

And I need to get something like this

```
https://habrahabr.ru/post/340400/
```

How to split two symbols `? &`

Comment: Why do you need to split two? You could just split the url using ? and just join everything before the ?

Comment: Try this:

`str = "https://habrahabr.ru/post/340400/?utm_source=habrahabr&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=best"`
`str.split("?")[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this. I would suggest to use `URI` module for urls:

```
URI(str).tap { |uri| uri.query = nil }.to_s
#=> "https://habrahabr.ru/post/340400/"
```